# Сравнить с предыдущим значением

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет, есть запрос в бд, из него выводятся данные, через `mysql_fetch_array` циклом.

```
$sql = mysql_query("***");
while($rowsql = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo $rowsql['stat'];
}
```

Как сравнить `$rowsql['stat']` с предыдущим значением?

Comment: ну записывайте в переменную в конце цикла и сравнивайте, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$prev = "";
while($rowsql = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    //сравнивайте $prev и $rowsql['stat']
    echo $rowsql['stat'];

    $prev = $rowsql['stat'];//запомнили предыдущее значение
   }
```